# How do I save table style visibility style after reload / refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a table containing a table, aka nested tables. (Person -> Pets data for example). First table displays all people, second table shows pets for each person.

I have a button which shows the nested table, this shows/hides the table data containing the pets.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function toggletable(id) {
  var tableid = document.getElementById(id);
  tableid.style.display = (tableid.style.display == "table") ? "none" : "table";
}
```

Now, if I refresh the page all tables are "none" again. However, I want so that if I open a table, aka click on the button that calls the function to open it, if I refresh the page it should be open again.

**Here is the button**

```
button id="toggleTableDisplay" class="button-sma" onclick="toggleTable((php echo ($data->get('id')); ?>) php echo "Show pets"?></button>
```

**Here is the table**

```
table name="php echo ($data->get('id')); ?>" style="display: none"  id="php echo ($data->get('id'));"
```

I'm not 100% sure how the formatting here works but I had to change the code so if you copy/paste it won't work as I've had to remove some ?> etc.

I put it in a pastebin here:

https://pastebin.com/YH1xS4XB

Comment: Store the tables visibility state in a `localStorage` and restore it on page load.

Comment: Hm okay, how would this work? I have no experience with it. Can I save an array with the ids and loop over on load?

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` keeps key->value pairs. So you might store tables id's as keys (since you'r using id's already) and an integer 1 for visibility flag as a value. When you reveal a table you just run something like:

```
localStorage.setItem(table_id, '1');
```

When you hide it, just drop the entry:

```
localStorage.removeItem(table_id);
```

And on page load you walk through your tables and show them if localStorage entry exists (jQuery here):

```
$('table').each(function(){
    if( localStorage.getItem( $(this).attr('id') ) )
         $(this).show();
})
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help. The only part I am unsure of is how to handle the new button function. Of course setitem and removeitem but the .show(); and .hide(); does not seem to work when I try to add it to the button.

But at the same time I should keep a toggle for it, I guess I can a dummy variable and check so it toggles correctly

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery, i brought such the code to be laconic. You might go for the styles directly `this.style.display = "table"` or manipulate classes (which is actually preferable) like `this.classList.add('active')`.